# How can I transfer members of a Telegram channel to another Telegram channel

Tags: bots, telegram, channel

How can I transfer members of a Telegram channel  (which I am their admin) or a group (or a super group) to another Telegram channel or group (which I am not their admin)?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use telethon its very easy and you have a lots of documentation out there.

For you specific question

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest

client(InviteToChannelRequest(
channel=SomeChannelId, 
users = ['SomeUserName']
))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used telethon:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
import asyncio

# Use your own values from my.telegram.org
api_id = 12345
api_hash = 'a1a1a1a1a1a1a11'

channel_to_name = 'migrate_to'
channel_from_name = 'migrate_from'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
loop.run_until_complete(client.connect())
channel_from = loop.run_until_complete(client.get_entity(channel_from_name))
channel_to = loop.run_until_complete(client.get_entity(channel_to_name))
users = client.iter_participants(channel_from)
users_arr = []
for user in users:
    users_arr.append(user)
loop.run_until_complete(client(InviteToChannelRequest(
        channel_to,
        users_arr
    )))
```